# Launch email intent with Linkify, subject header

Tags: android, email, linkify

I've managed to set up the launch of an email using linkify, and I have also learned how to create an intent with the subject set, and send an email by calling startActivity with that intent specified.

However, my question is how how to get linkify to launch an intent I create - for the purposes of setting the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subject is fixed (i.e., you're declaring it), you should be able to use `addLinks()` on `Linkify` with your own `MatchFilter` and `TransformFilter` to create `mailto:` links for whatever pattern you like, and include the `?subject=...` part on the link.